# Tomcat sometimes not accepting connections - Nginx 502

Tags: java, tomcat, nginx

I have a following setup:
AWS ELB -> Nginx -> Tomcat

Most of the time everything works great but once in a while in Ngnix error log I see the following error:

> 2016/07/20 13:18:49 [error] 1980#0: *52053 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream

I've increased limits for open files, number of connections for Ngnix and also for Tomcat.

Tomcat connector:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
    redirectPort="8443"
    URIEncoding="UTF-8"
    acceptorThreadCount="2"
    maxKeepAliveRequests="-1"
    connectionTimeout="-1"
    maxConnections="-1"
    acceptCount="1000"
    maxThreads="32000" />
```

Ngnix:

```
server {
listen       80;
server_name  a.example.com;

location / {
    proxy_pass              http://localhost:8080/a/;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header        Host $http_host;
}
}

server {
listen       80;
server_name  b.example.com;

location / {
    proxy_pass              http://localhost:8080/b/;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header        Host $http_host;
}
}
```

There are no errors in Catalina.out and no entries in Tomcat localhost_access_log file.
It happens on all four server nodes, it's not related to time of day nor load of the servers.
I've been debugging it for four days already and are out of ideas what is happening.

Comment: Why would you have AWS ELB and Nginx set up in your cluster? ELB and Nginx do the same job...

Comment: In Nginx conf there are multiple server directives which direct traffic to different URLs in Tomcat. I've added Nginx conf to the inital post.